# VideoView preventing other fragments in a ViewPager from showing up?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple Android program which uses ViewPager to swipe between two tabs. Each tab has its own fragment. One fragment plays video while the other simply shows some text. The problem is when the video plays and I swipe to the information tab there is no text and it is completely black. I know it must be because of the video layout. Reason being is I have tested it with two information tabs instead and the information shows up perfectly on each tab. Here's my code.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ViewPager tabsviewPager;
     private ActionBar mActionBar;
     private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabsviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabspager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        tabsviewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab friendstab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Daily Video").setTabListener(this);
        Tab publicprofiletab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Video Details").setTabListener(this);


        getSupportActionBar().addTab(friendstab);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(publicprofiletab);


        //This helps in providing swiping effect for v7 compat library 
        tabsviewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

     @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab selectedtab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tabsviewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedtab.getPosition()); //update tab position on tap
    }

     @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

TabsAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

     private int TOTAL_TABS = 2;

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new VideoFragment();

            case 1:
                return new InfoFragment();

            }

            return null;
    }

     @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TOTAL_TABS;
    }

}

VideoFragment.java

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_layout, container, false);
        VideoView vView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoViewLoop);
        vView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Snapchat/Hansen.mp4");
        vView.setOnPreparedListener (new OnPreparedListener() {  
          @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.setLooping(true);
            }
       });
        vView.start();  

       return view;
    }
}
```

InfoFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabspager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

info_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This Will Show Details of Video Location and Also the Amount of User Viewings"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

video_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoViewLoop" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [Possibly related but no solution either](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36340085/1034042)