# Nested Fragment with VideoView streaming takes too long while stopping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I have a tab UI, with a Fragment Tab host at bottom and fragments in a container fragment. Every time I change Tab I switch between fragments within the container fragment.

Now the issue is as below:
I have a fragment with a video view streaming live video. while the video is buffering if I press back key the fragment takes too long to stop. I can see a big lag of 2-3 seconds from the time onStop() of this fragment till oCreateView() of other fragment. All my other methods like onDestroy, onDestroyVeiw() etc are empty.

I have come to a conclusion that it is because the video view is busy with initialization/buffering it take  android time to stop all these activities synchronously in video view and then stops the fragment.

What I am looking for is  to stop the video buffering Asynchronously.. so that my UI for next fragment is not shown with the lag.

regards,

ticks_sunny

Comment: Got the same thing, with a FragmentPager. 4 VideoViews on one page, and waits a good 4-9s when I switch to another. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31841793/1034042) is a related question with no answer either.